# C++ STL Vector: Cleanly convert `std::size_t` index to iterator with `-Wsign-conversion`

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, stdvector, compiler-warnings

When working with [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), is there a way to convert an index of type `std::size_t` to a corresponding iterator, without generating any warnings when `-Wsign-conversion` is enabled (GCC, Clang), and preferably without using `static_cast`?

It seems the standard ways to convert an index to an iterator assume a signed index, and so generate a warning when the index is an unsigned type. This is rather unfortunate, as the natural index type for a `std::vector` is an unsigned type, and data access using a signed index would then generated sign conversion warnings.

As a motivating example, methods such as [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) require an iterator, and there is no apparent alternative to `erase` directly using an index.

Consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::size_t index = 1;

    data[index]; // No warning
    const auto iterator = std::next(data.begin(), index); // Warning

    data.erase(iterator);

    return 0;
}
```

When compile with either GCC or Clang, with `-Wsign-conversion`, a warning is generated:

```
g++ -Wsign-conversion main.cpp
```

> main.cpp:12:55: warning: conversion to ‘std::__iterator_traits<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector >, void>::difference_type’ {aka ‘long int’} from ‘std::size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]

Changing the index type from `std::size_t` to `int` isn't much of a solution, since data access (`data[index]`) would then generate a warning instead. Data access of course being the more common case.

Using pointer arithmetic doesn't help either, as that also generates a sign conversion warning:

```cpp
const auto iterator = data.begin() + index;
```

What does work is a `static_cast`, though that's hardly desirable and opens up questions about possible range differences and undefined behaviour:

```cpp
const auto iterator = std::next(data.begin(), static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(index));
```

Kind of feels like there's a big hole in the API design here if the only way to `erase` by the natural index type in a `std::vector` requires a `static_cast` (to silence sign conversion warnings, when enabled).

Comment: There's a reason why `-Wsign-conversion` is not enabled by `-Wall` or even `-Wextra` -- its an almost useless warning as it is a 'normal' thing that happens all the time.

Comment: While it is called `next`, both `next` and `prev` are really just named wrappers for `return it + offset;`.  Since C++ allows negative offsets, `next` and `prev` both take signed types.  While the warning is valid, in practice on a 64 bit system you'll never overflow.

Comment: *"there's a big hole in the API design here"*  Yes, the standards committee has apologized for making the size_type unsigned. In retrospect, it was a mistake.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Perhaps, though there are certainly valid uses of `-Wsign-compare`, and documented cases of security exploits due to sloppy checks in code that require sign conversion. Granted, the examples I've seen of security exploits have generally been in the reverse direction of converting a signed value to unsigned (where a max check was done on the signed value, but no consideration was given to negative signed values and how they convert to unsigned).

Comment: @NathanOliver: Negative offsets do make sense in some contexts, though unsigned values have well defined wrap around, which means an unsigned offset still works just as well, even in the negative case. Perhaps even better since you never have to worry about undefined behaviour. And although typically code may not overflow, there are cases of security exploits, where an attacker may try to force an overflow in some unexpected way.

Comment: @BoP: Sarcasm aside, the solution seems to be quite contrary, as defining `std::ptrdiff_t` to be unsigned would have solved the issue, and with well defined wrap around for unsigned values, there would have been no loss of functionality. In many ways signed values are the problem, not unsigned values.

Comment: @DanielStevens That argument only works on modern system.  C++ used to support implementations on signed magnitude and ones compliment machines.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Sure, there were some interesting systems back in the day. Though the C++ standard defines wraparound behaviour for unsigned quantities. It's the signed quantities that have undefined wraparound behaviour, and would be of most concern when working with those ancient systems.

Answer (score 0):

> Using pointer arithmetic doesn't help either, as that also generates a sign conversion warning:
>
> ```
> const auto iterator = data.begin() + index;
> ```

So, if one has only a hammer, everything else always looks like a nail:

```
const auto iterator=data.begin()+static_cast<long>(index);
```

No more warnings. Sometimes, a carbon-based life-form knows more, and needs to outwit, a compiler.

Comment: Yes, this is basically equivalent to the `static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>` from the example. As @NathanOliver pointed out, [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) and [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) effectively translate to that when using random access iterators.